# I am not able to add plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins

In jenkins I am not able to add plugins,when I search for plugins I am getting a message as in the picture.

[image]

Comment: It could be a proxy issue. Have you verified your browser proxy?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have installed a plugin, but have yet to restart your Jenkins instance. If Jenkins is running as a service, simply stop and start the service command line, or check the checkbox in your screenshot above to restart Jenkins when no jobs are running and refresh the browser.

Should do the trick.